# Why UI-Router has stopped using hash character?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, server-side-rendering

I have started to see something about Angular2, in particular UI-router states and routes. What I noticed is that contrary to Ang1 now I must not use **'#'** character in order to navigate from a route to another.
This implies that if I go to state `foo`, which is routed as `/foo`, I've to type:

*mydomain.com/app/foo*

instead of the old *mydomain.com/app/#/foo*

This obviously start a HTTP request to url */foo* in the server. In Ang1 response of course would be a 404 (unless I previously create a static ghost page, e.g. for crawler), but with Ang2 I get the same html (the index.html) as I asked for:

*mydomain.com/app/*

which is basically a "loading...." page.

What I'd like to understand is how is that possible, and if this is linked to the  serverside-rendering feature that new generation frameworks offer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since HTML5 client-side routing is possible, without using the "#".
Using this HTML5-Mode, was also possible in AngularJS, but you needed to enable it:

```
$locationprovider.html5Mode(true)
```

In Angular (Version 2.X.X and greater) however, the HTML5-Mode is enabled by default.
If you want to use it, you need to be aware of 2 things:
- Not all browsers support that mode.
- The server needs to support HTML5-Mode

If you still want to use the "#", you need to enable it. To do that, add the following provider to your root `NgModule`:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#-hashlocationstrategy-) and `useHash: true`:

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

Without the hash uses HTML [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

Your summary of the benefits and drawbacks of each is pretty good. When using pushState (rather than useHash), your server will have to handle the routes correctly, but your routes will look cleaner. It's a trade-off.

To get a little more specific about server handling, the distinction applies if you want to be able to bookmark any route other than the root (such as `/app/foo`) and return to it later (e.g. from a refresh or new browser or tab). With `useHash: false` (pushState), your server would have to be configured specially to map those routes, and serve up the client correctly for those cases. However, with `useHash: true`, no such special server-side handling is required; you would only have one server-side endpoint, the root; the hash fragment is handled entirely by the browser, per web standards.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get how server relates to this. As far as I understand pushState doesn't trigger any page reload, so how is possible that I see the request of the page?

Comment: To clarify, the distinction applies if you want to be able to bookmark any route other than the root (such as `/app/foo`) and return to it later (e.g. from a refresh or new browser or tab). With `useHash: false` (pushState), your server would have to be configured specially to map those routes, and serve up the client correctly for those cases. However, with `useHash: true`, no such special server-side handling is required; you would only have one server-side endpoint, the root; the hash fragment is handled entirely by the browser, per web standards.